# Need to implement a method after every click or swipe event using appium

Tags: appium

Implement a method after every action e.g click, sendkeys that my script performs using appium driver. My current class has method calls which includes snippets as follows :

```
waitForElementPresent("lgn_btn", 2);   
driver.findElement(getBy("lgn_btn")).click();  
//perform action                                 
driver.findElement(getBy("lgn_email")).click();      
//perform action     
driver.findElement(getBy("clr_btn")).click(); 
//perform action
waitForElementPresent("email_num_btn"), 2);        
driver.findElement(getBy("email_num_btn")).sendKeys(email);
//perform action
```

I want to implement an Observer in Java to replace "perform action".
Need help related to which class for AppiumDriver events can I create as Observable to trace the events called and implemented in my class which would extend Observer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create your own class that extends existing WebDriver functionality.
Its constructor initializes driver and implement your own `findElement` method e.g.

```
static WebElement findElement(By by) {       
 def result = mobileDriver.findElement(by)
//perform custom additional action
    return result
}
```

Comment: can i do it for the click() OR sendkeys() as well?